# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes at random

Tags: 16.04, freeze, toshiba-satellite

I am running a fresh install of `Ubuntu 16.04` on my `Toshiba Satellite L50`. Fairly often (once per hour or so) it randomly freezes. The system is installed in UEFI mode, although it had the same problem during a test install in Legacy. The previous install of Linux Mint 17.2 worked with no problems.

### I've tried the following:

- Updating kernel to `4.6.2`
- Installing Nvidia prime
- Trying to enter shell by pressing `ctrl + alt +f3` (alternatively `ctrl + alt+ f1`)

I've been searching for a solution for a long time now, with no result. Can somebody help?

[This](http://pastebin.com/sfND0UNG) a copy of syslog, the freeze happened aproximately at 22:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question, maybe it will help somebody in the future. After many trial and error, it seems that disabling VT-x option in UEFI options seem to solved the freezing.

So far running a few days without problems.

Comment: Was that the full solution? I have the same problem but I need VT-x enabled for Virtual Machines...

Comment: Yes, I didn't really need the feature so disabling it worked for me.

Comment: where is VT-x option in UEFI options

Answer (score 0):

Adding `noapic` to the kernel boot parameters also solves the problem, and you can keep virtualization enabled.

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`
2. Add `noapic` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`
3. Run `update-grub`